# Whate does "nighty build" mean?

Tags: apache-http-server

I was implementing to Apache-James server then I found *James nightly builds*.
What is this *James nightly builds* and which is better,  *James* or *James nightly build*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nightly builds are the latest builds that pass whatever sorts of tests that the project development has has set up. They contain the latest features, but they might also be unstable.

In a production environment, you should probably not be running nightly builds of anything. The latest release will be far more stable and have much better tests. Only run the nightly builds if they have a feature you absolutely need to carry out your mission, and make sure you test the system extensively to make sure there are no problems.